# Similarity between 2 profiles (observations). Is it possible to generate a % similarity?

Tags: normalization, standardization, k-nearest-neighbour, similarities, euclidean

I have multiple profiles for 10 different people. Each person has been measured for 5 different continuous variables of different magnitudes. So my dataframe is 10x5 where each row represents a person (observation).

What I want to be able to do is return a % similarity between any pair of the two profiles. I have seen the use of distance measures e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/philentropy/vignettes/Distances.html. To show that the pair with the smallest distance are the most similar, but this is not expressed as a % similarity? Is it possible to convert the distance to a %, or other measures to express similarity as a %? Alternatively could you use knn with only 1 neighbour?

Further, I am assuming that each continuous measure should be normalised so that all are on the same scale? Or should is standardise?

Comment: You could do the distance approach and standardize the distances to [0,1] which you can interpret as %.

Comment: Hi, this would not represent the profile a is x% the same as profile b. More like profile a and c are the most similar (lowest distance) so they (when standardised) would have the lowest value =0. And any comparison would be relative to this value. Anywayto avoid being relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most usual way to estimate the similarity should be to use the euclidian distance through a gaussian function:

$S = exp(-\frac{d^2}{2\sigma^2})$

where $\sigma$ is a characteristic length that is yours to be defined. You can also have several $\sigma$ values (one for each feature of your set, for instance), in case your data is not normalized:

$S(x_i, x_j) = exp(-\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^d{\frac{x_i^{(k)} - x_j^{(k)}}{\sigma_k^2}})$

where $x_i$ and $x_j$ are two observations, $d$ is the number of features, $\sigma_k$ is the characteristic distance in each direction, and $x_i^{(k)}$ the $k$-th component of $x_i$.

Please note that there are many other ways of doing so. You just need to give yourself a distance function and a *kernel* function (as the gaussian kernel above). You could for instance use the earth mover's distance and a [polynomial kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel) capped from 0 to 1. It all depends on how you see your data.

Comment: Appreciate the response. Is it possible to calculate a % similarity from this approach however. When expressing similarity as a distance it is hard to convey.

Comment: Well the gaussian kernel gives you a value between 0 and 1 that you can scale from 0% to 100%. A 100% similarity would thus mean that the distance is equal to 0. With this gaussian expression of similarity, you cannot reach a 0 % value, but this totally depends on the kernel you choose.
Or perhaps am I missing something in your question?